# Combining compressed Gzipped Text Files using Java

Tags: java, gzip, zcat

my question might not be entirely related to Java but I'm currently seeking a method to combine several compressed (gzipped) textfiles without the requirement to recompress them manually. Lets say I have 4 files, all text that is compressed using gzip and want to compress these into one single *.gz file without de + recompressing them. My current method is to open an InputStream and parse the file linewise, storing in a GZIPoutputstream, which works but isn't very fast.... I could of course also call

```
    zcat file1 file2 file3 | gzip -c > output_all_four.gz
```

This would work, too but isn't really fast either.

My idea would be to copy the inputstream and write it to outputstream directly without "parsing" the stream, as I don't need to manipulate anything actually. Is something like this possible?

Comment: What about using `cat file1 file2 file3 > output_all_three.gz`?

Comment: In theory: Yes. Practically, lots of tools then think of the output as separate files, meaning they don't work on the output in this way.

Comment: Which `lots of tools` do you mean? `gzip` is not fooled, Java is not fooled. And using `gzip` that way is a valid case http://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/html_node/Advanced-usage.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find below a simple solution in Java (it does the same as my `cat ...` example). Any kind of buffering the input/output has been omitted to keep the code slim.

```
public class ConcatFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // concatenate the single gzip files to one gzip file
        try (InputStream isOne = new FileInputStream("file1.gz");
                InputStream isTwo = new FileInputStream("file2.gz");
                InputStream isThree = new FileInputStream("file3.gz");
                SequenceInputStream sis =  new SequenceInputStream(new SequenceInputStream(isOne, isTwo), isThree);
                OutputStream bos = new FileOutputStream("output_all_three.gz")) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int intsRead;
            while ((intsRead = sis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, intsRead);
            }
            bos.flush();
        }

        // ungezip the single gzip file, the output contains the
        // concatenated input of the single uncompressed files 
        try (GZIPInputStream gzipis = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("output_all_three.gz"));
                OutputStream bos = new FileOutputStream("output_all_three")) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int intsRead;
            while ((intsRead = gzipis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, intsRead);
            }
            bos.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above method works if you just require to gzip many zipped files. In my case I had made a web servlet and my response was in 20-30 KBs. So I was sending the zipped response.

I tried to zip all my individual JS files on server start only and then add dynamic code runtime using the above method. I could print the entire response in my log file but chrome was able to unzip the first file only. Rest output was coming in bytes.

After research I found out that this is not possible with chrome and they have closed the bug also without solving it.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20884